# PHP Cart Contents Print Out

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql, xhtml

I have a simple shop displaying data from PostgreSQL database:

```
$database  = pg_connect("host= port= ");
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 ';

$query .= ' ORDER BY Price';
$result = pg_query($database, $query);
echo '<form name="basket" action="basket.php" method="post">' . '<table border="1" class="center">';
echo "<tr></tr>";
while ($a = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='games[]' value='.$id.' ></td>";
for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($result); $j++) {
    echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo '</table>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="Add To Basket" value="Add To Basket" />
</form>
```

When the some checkboxes are checked and submit is hit, I want to see the checked products on the cart.php.

My current cart.php code is:

```
$games = $_POST['games'];
.......
var_dump($games);
print_r($games);
```

But this gives the output:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) ".." [1]=> string(2) ".." [2]=> string(2) ".." [3]=> string(2) ".." } Array ( [0] => .. [1] => .. [2] => .. [3] => .. )
```

Could anybody help me out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$id` value in checkbox, added as `$id = $a[0];`

```
    while ($a = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
       $id = $a[0];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='games[]' value='$id' ></td>";
        for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($result); $j++) {
            echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding `.` to your field values, e.g. `value=".7."`

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='games[]' value='.$id.' ></td>";
                                                       ^---^--
```

You also aren't defining `$id` anywhere, so you're outputting an undefined variable, which will product a blank spot.